# Эксплуатирование Shellshock

Tags: linux, безопасность

На VM Ware у меня стоит Kali Linux и Metasploitable 2. Команда `ifconfig` дает `IP`-адрес виртуальной машины с Metasploitable, и этот адрес доступен из браузера. На кали я формирую запросы такого вида:

```
curl -H "User-Agent: () { :;}; echo vuln" <IP-адрес>
curl -H "User-Agent: () { :;}; /bin/nc -p 4444 -l -e /bin/bash &" <IP-адрес>
```

Но на виртуалке с Metasploitable ничего не происходит. В ответ просто возвращается логотип и набор 'html'-тегов. Как правильно использовать эту уязвимость и убедиться в том, что цель достигнута?

Comment: А на какой порт вы это шлете и что там стоит на этом порту с обратной стороны. Shellshock не смотря на то, сколько про него кричали можно эксплуатировать в довольно экзотических условиях. Например если web-сервер apache запуская cgi-скрипт будет использовать для этого bash. Что не применяется например, при запуске php скриптов (которые обрабатывает встроенный в apache модуль). Так же apache не придет в голову запускать bash для отдачи статического контента

Comment: Должно идти на 80 по умолчанию, там же апач стоит.

Comment: Ну так апач сам bash никогда не вызывет. Это может сделать только cgi-скрипт который на нем работает. Но очень мало какие cgi-скрипты используют в своей работе запуск других программ с помощью system, которая запустит bash в случае если он стоит шеллом по умолчанию и если аргументы у этого system подходящие.

Comment: Так что фактически shellshock через апач применим в 0.0001% случаев, когда в качестве cgi-скриптов используются bash-скрипты, например.

Comment: Печально. Когда нам показывали успешную эксплуатацию, никто ничего не понял, и у этого аспиранта очень невнятная устная речь, он часто сбивается, следить за его мыслями тяжело. А я нагуглил только то, что не работает на моей системе.

Comment: Ну так что бы продемонстровать shellshock надо специально подготовить уж очень уязвимый скрипт, который до этого наверняка уже взломали бы десятком других способов. проблема говорят более актуальна для DHCP-серверов, потому как они запускают внешние скрипты передавая данные от клиента через окружения и то, по моему это довольно натянутая проблема, потому как скрипты по умолчанию у dhcp отсутствуют и он ничего не запускает

Comment: Так что на локальной машине попробуйте, просто убедитесь что старые версии bash могут запустить что то из окружения :)

Comment: Говорят даже, что если шеллшок где-то и работает, то только в качестве honeypot'а. Кек.